# Magento 2. Uncaught SyntaxError: Expected property name or '}' in JSON at position 1

Tags: magento2, javascript, json

I need help. In Chrome console I receive Error.
I don't know where to look for the error and how to fix it.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Expected property name or '}' in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at getData (main.js:58:24)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at HTMLDocument.apply (main.js:74:18)
at fire (jquery.js:3238:32)
at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3297:8)
at jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3548:26)
at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2973:11)
at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-migrate.js:241:16)
at jQuery (jquery.js:80:11)
```

---

I don't know where to look for the error. Previously everything worked, now ajax add to cart, minicart and in checkout Proceed to Checkout button not working.

getData (main.js:58:24)

```
    data: JSON.parse(data)
```

main.js

```
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

define([
'underscore',
'jquery',
'./scripts'
], function (_, $, processScripts) {
'use strict';

var dataAttr = 'data-mage-init',
    nodeSelector = '[' + dataAttr + ']';

/**
 * Initializes components assigned to a specified element via data-* attribute.
 *
 * @param {HTMLElement} el - Element to initialize components with.
 * @param {Object|String} config - Initial components' config.
 * @param {String} component - Components' path.
 */
function init(el, config, component) {
    require([component], function (fn) {

        if (typeof fn === 'object') {
            fn = fn[component].bind(fn);
        }

        if (_.isFunction(fn)) {
            fn(config, el);
        } else if ($(el)[component]) {
            $(el)[component](config);
        }
    }, function (error) {
        if ('console' in window && typeof window.console.error === 'function') {
            console.error(error);
        }

        return true;
    });
}

/**
 * Parses elements 'data-mage-init' attribute as a valid JSON data.
 * Note: data-mage-init attribute will be removed.
 *
 * @param {HTMLElement} el - Element whose attribute should be parsed.
 * @returns {Object}
 */
function getData(el) {
    var data = el.getAttribute(dataAttr);

    el.removeAttribute(dataAttr);

    return {
        el: el,
        data: JSON.parse(data)
    };
}

return {
    /**
     * Initializes components assigned to HTML elements via [data-mage-init].
     *
     * @example Sample 'data-mage-init' declaration.
     *      data-mage-init='{"path/to/component": {"foo": "bar"}}'
     */
    apply: function (context) {
        var virtuals = processScripts(!context ? document : context),
            nodes = document.querySelectorAll(nodeSelector);

        _.toArray(nodes)
            .map(getData)
            .concat(virtuals)
            .forEach(function (itemContainer) {
                var element = itemContainer.el;

                _.each(itemContainer.data, function (obj, key) {
                        if (obj.mixins) {
                            require(obj.mixins, function () { //eslint-disable-line max-nested-callbacks
                                var i, len;

                                for (i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
                                    $.extend(
                                        true,
                                        itemContainer.data[key],
                                        arguments[i](itemContainer.data[key], element)
                                    );
                                }

                                delete obj.mixins;
                                init.call(null, element, obj, key);
                            });
                        } else {
                            init.call(null, element, obj, key);
                        }

                    }
                );

            });
    },
    applyFor: init
};
});
```

Answer (score 2):

HERE THE SOLUTION....
The error message "Uncaught SyntaxError: Expected property name or '}' in JSON at position 1" indicates that there is a syntax error in a JSON object, and the error occurred at the first character of the JSON string.

To fix the error, you can follow these steps:

Open the Chrome Developer Tools by pressing F12 or right-clicking on the page and selecting "Inspect".
Go to the "Console" tab.
Look for the line number indicated in the error message (in this case, line 58 of main.js).
Inspect the code around that line to see if there is a syntax error in a JSON object.
If you find the syntax error, fix it and save the file. If you're not sure how to fix it, you can ask for help from a developer.
Once you fix the syntax error, refresh the page and check if the error message is gone.

Answer (score 0):

To find the source of the error, you can follow these steps:

1. Look at the console error message to see if there are any additional details or hints about the problem.
2. Check the line number in the error message to see where the error is occurring.
3. Open the JavaScript file (main.js) referenced in the error message and navigate to the line number indicated.
4. Look for any JSON data or objects that are being parsed or created at the line number indicated.
5. Check the JSON syntax to see if there are any obvious errors with property names, brackets, or quotes.
6. If you are still unable to find the error, try adding console.log statements to the code to see what data is being passed to the JSON.parse function.
7. Once you have identified the error, you can try to fix the syntax or use a JSON validator to ensure that your data is correctly formatted.
8. Remember to clear your browser cache and reload the page after making any changes to the code to see if the error has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I found error. I don't know how it happened but in the CMS block I had

```
data-mage-init="{"
```

I removed it and all works fine.